# libgdx Gradle Project Import Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I am new to libgdx and i followed everything that the tutorial says. I have also added

```
-Dosgi.configuration.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area=@user.dir
```

to my eclipse.ini file. The error I get is(cannot post image becoz reputation is less than 10) :

```
null
see error log for details
```

I have eclipse version 4.1(Juno)

Please Help. I am very exited to develop 2d games. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We could help more if you stated which tutorial you were following

Comment: @BasimKhajwal I am following this tutorial:-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9fs1PVTyUc&list=PLaNw_AbDFccHbzuObI4xHHp6WtiN2cRQv&index=51